# Python generate rainbow rgb by percentage of animation

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to animate text just by changing its color using all the rainbow colors.

I've got an array

```
COLORS = [255, 0, 0]
```

I only need these three integers to change. Now I have the function

```
def getRGB(percentage):
    global COLORS
    COLORS[0] = ...
    COLORS[1] = ...
    COLORS[2] = ...
```

The parameter `percentage` is a float from 0 to 1, indicating at which position the loop currently is.

The `getRGB` function will be called n times a second, and it should set the `COLORS` values to the resulting RGB values.

*How the result should look:*

```
getRGB(0) -> [255, 0, 0]
getRGB(1) -> [255, 0, 0]
getRGB(0.5) -> [0, 255, 255]
```

Comment: What have you tried? The way I solved this was to treat the color as a 3-digit, base 255 number, then just increment it

Comment: @Carcigenicate I haven't really tried anything so far, because I looked at it and didn't get a clue on how to approach this problem. I think I can't use base 255 numbers, because I must not include any libraries.

Comment: You don't need any libraries, just some math. Looking up base conversion formulas might be worth it. This is how I tackled the problem, and it worked for me. It would be far too long of an answer to post here though. This isn't a site to request guides when you haven't tried anything, so you may have difficulty getting a good answer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I can imagine that this might be too long, but I think there must be a different solution, one which is short enough.